# What git branch was I just in?

Tags: git

My workflow often consists of the following:

- working on a long term feature branch (call it 'A')
- checking out master and making a hotfix branch (call it 'B')
- pushing my hotfix
- Then I forget what branch I was working on before that...

Is there any sort of git history that will show me that the thing I was previously working on was branch A?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
git reflog
```

which will list all of your recent actions that changed something, so checkout, rebase, pull, push, etc.

Also it includes all the commit ids, so for example if you did a dozen `commit --amend` you can jump back to one in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

As documented in [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), the syntax `@{-number}` refers to the branch checked out *number* occurrences ago.  This uses the *reflogs*, specifically the reflog for `HEAD`; see [Duncan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45376683/1256452).

(In your particular example you'd want `@{-1}`.  For `git checkout` you can abbreviate this as `git checkout -`, but that only works for `git checkout`.)

Comment: @Duncan: yes; I would peruse the reflog for anything more than "where was I just a moment ago" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
git branch --sort=-committerdate
```

or

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/heads/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout -
```

go to the the previously used branch

I've also set this alias that prints the last 10 branches I've worked on :

```
[alias]
    recent = for-each-ref --count=10 --sort=-committerdate refs/heads/ --format='%(refname:short) %(committerdate:relative)'
```